# ASP.NET Web API - HttpClient.PostAsync local API does not step into code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

So here's my situation...

I have a unit test project wherein I instantiated a Web API controller. Both the unit test project and the ASP.NET Web API project are in the same solution. The Web API controllers' implementation includes one part that is to call HttpClient.PostAsync to another Web API that is in another solution and is deployed to local IIS.

The project of the caller method and the project that is deployed to IIS are both opened in Visual Studio (2 VS windows opened). I have already copied the pdb and all from the solution that is deployed to IIS to the bin/debug folder of the unit test project.

But everytime the control goes to the PostAsync call, when I pressed F11, it doesn't get into the code that is opened in another VS editor.

May I know how will I be able to achieve this?

Unit Test project:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestController
{
TestController t = new TestController();
t.Get();
}
```

TestController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get()
{

//assume that HttpClient.BaseAddress was already set in constructor

client.PostAsync("/testapi/getdata");
}
```

Controller in another solution, deployed in IIS

```
[Route("testapi/getdata")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get()
{
//implementation here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling the API using Post, but your Api is accepting only Get

```
client.PostAsync("/testapi/getdata");

///Controller in another solution, deployed in IIS

[Route("testapi/getdata")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()
```

you have to change client.GetAsync maybe or you can use post but change api.

and when you use async you have to use await or Result, but await is preferable

```
 awant client.GetAsync("/testapi/getdata")
//or
client.GetAsync("/testapi/getdata").Result;

///Controller in another solution, deployed in IIS

[Route("testapi/getdata")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Get()

// but should be
public async Task<ActionResult> Get()
```

UPDATE

you have updated your question, but after this it looks even more strange

```
[Route("testapi/getdata")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Get()
```

for getdata without any input parameters and null request body you select HttpPost.

```
client.PostAsync("/testapi/getdata");
```

It will not be even compiled, since post needs content.

I am wondering what is  API controller like. Does it have an attribute route too? Or all your code is just a fake?

Comment: edited the code. forgot that it must be HttpPost

Comment: @Joseph You didn't fix another bug, since you use async you have to use await or result.

Comment: I haven't pasted the complete code since I just typed it manually. and yes I know about the async/ await. I mean you know the gist.

Comment: You don't need to know what the controller look like. I just need to know how can the control step into the code which is in another solution when the breakpoint reaches the postasync call.

Comment: It will never step, if for example your route is wrong,  or your post request is wrong, the same as you posted. How we can give you advise, if your code is fake, and can't be even compilled. We are just waisting our valuable time during the weekend.

Comment: I mean, I could actually have not included the sample code in my question, but I included just for demonstration like a pseudocode in case my question wasn't clear. There is an answer after your answer, He was able to understand what I meant but after trying his suggestion, didn't worked out too.

Comment: @Joseph He suggested  just one reason, but there are another reasons too.  We are  not magicans,  we need the code that can be compilled to test.

Comment: Understood what you meant, but for this particular question, hope readers will focus on the question and treat the code part as pseudocode for demo purposes.

Comment: The most  httpclient post code is working properly without any problem. But we even don't know what ar you using - httpclient or something else.

Comment: //assume that HttpClient.BaseAddress was already set in constructor - pls take a look

Comment: It maybe name client , it maybe httpclient factory, typed client and so on. You should post the whole code if you really need some help.

Comment: @Joseph And also the most API need JWT or something like it. I just posted the bugs, that I noticed, but  you can have much more.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. Receiving a 200 response when calling an action method on an API controller, but the breakpoint in the controller never got hit, nor was the code executed.

When inspecting the the response content, I noticed it contained the HTML of the Microsoft login page. It was failing to authenticate the request.

So in my case, and in the non production, development environment the solution was to decorate the action method with the

```
[AllowAnonymous]
```

data attribute.

The breakpoint got hit and testing could continue without fiddling with / mocking authentication tokens in headers or impersonating.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot share debugging instances in Visual Studio between 2 solutions when the other solution is not in debug mode.

Run the other solution within Visual Studio itself (in a separate instance, on a different port) & place a breakpoint where the request should hit - `Get()`.

Make sure the API is being run in debug mode and not release mode for any breakpoints to be hit.

The request from solution 1 should then hit the breakpoint in the controller in solution 2 and allow you to step into the request as needed.

*P.S. you don't need to deal with PDB files for this - your issue is how you're running the second solution/API.*

Comment: I run the unit test solution under debug mode. When it steps inside the TestController Get method, control goes to the PostAsync. When I press F11 when the control is in the PostAsync, it does not step into the code which is opened in another solution in another VS window. The code in postasync as states is running in a web site in IIS

Comment: No, you need to run the 2nd API in debug mode - IIS has no debugging features. You need to run the other solution in debug mode for anything to be stepped into - the debugger can't just attach itself to nothing

Comment: The PostAsync call to the 2nd API references to the deployment application folder which is in the IIS Website. You mean to say that I need to run the code for the 2nd API in debug mode and then run the unit test?

Comment: Correct, yes - the 2nd API needs to be running in debug mode as I mentioned in my answer - "Run the other solution within Visual Studio itself"

Comment: It does not work - after pressing F11 in the first solution reaching the PostAsync line and the 2nd solution API run in debug mode, it doesn't stepped into the code in the 2nd solution.

Comment: It 100% will if your code is correct. Your code is incorrect then (including but not limited to the points that [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11392290/serge) has mentioned.